# Use "normal" in function

Tags: vimscript, functions

I'm writing a function to automate some task.

I did this:

```
function InitTTbuffer()
    " Split file and find the first imap
    :exe "normal \<C-w>\<C-s>/imap\<CR>"

    "resize window to 9 lines (with z9>CR>) then scroll (zt)
    :exe "normal z9\<CR>zt"

    "and then return to my file and execute my mapping "se"
    :exe "normal \<C-w>\<DOWN>se"

endfunction
```

It works fine but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63672887/6266107) that the OP **must not use** `<CR>` nor `:exe` in his case.
I tried to remove the `:exe`, changing

```
:exe "normal z9\<CR>zt"
```

in:

```
normal z9
normal zt
```

but now the `z9` and `zt` aren't be executed.

Then, **my question**:

- In which way is my case different from the question in the link?
- And why my code now don't works?

Comment: according to the help, `zN` requires the `<CR>` so you must use `exe ":norm zt\<cr>"`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt `:normal! zt` works perfectly. The doc is about `z9<cr>` or `z1<cr>`. So yes, in that case, it must be `:exe "normal! z9\<cr>"`

Comment: yes, it's not required for `zt`. But if you want to chain them together, you'll need again the `:exe` call.

Answer (score 2):

According to the help at [:h z](https://vimhelp.org/index.txt.html#z)  the `zN` command requires the `<CR>`, so in that case you must use `:exe ":norm! z<nr>\<cr>"` (replace `<nr>` by an actual number).

Alternatively we can use `normal z<nr>^M` where `^M` is  inserted by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.
The colon (`:`) at the start of the row is unnecessary.

So everything okay, except that I would always recommend to use `:norm!` (with `bang` attribute, to be independent on what the user has actual mapped).

Comment: Thanks! I understand and I proved that there's no difference between `:normal` and `normal`.  But there's another question, now: there's a way better than the other, in terms of performance, speed, etc.?

Comment: @Antonio you won't see any differences. However if your trigger a lot of _redraw_, it may have consequences. BTW, I don't know which would be better between `:exe "normal! z9\<cr>"` and `:resize 9`. They seem to do the same things. (I'm not sure though)

Comment: I don't think the `:` is actually required, but I tend to write it, to make it explicit ‍♂️

Comment: @LucHermitte, I didn't know the `:resize` command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would restrict the use of `:help :normal` to where there is no better option:

```
function InitTTbuffer()
    " show current buffer in new 9 lines window and search for `imap`
    9split +/imap

    " scroll current line to top
    normal! zt

    " return to previous window
    wincmd p

    " execute se normal mode command
    normal! se
endfunction
```

The function is much more readable that way.

See `:help :split` and `:help :wincmd`.

--- EDIT ---

This line:

```
9split +/imap
```

could also be written:

```
9split | /imap
```

or even:

```
9split
/imap
```

The differences are subtle and may or may not always matter:

- `:help +cmd` provides a traditional and intuitive way to "open file X at line Y". I used it here because I use it often.
- `:help :|` can be used to chain several commands. It would work just as well, here, but it has a number of "issues". One is that the RHS of a `|` won't be executed if the LHS fails, which might be useful in some cases and surprising in others, for example. Also, especially in scenarios involving windows, the order of execution can be very surprising.
- The last one is the simplest, with an implicit `<CR>` between the commands.

Off the three, I consider the 1st and 3rd to be the safest and least surprising. I prefer to use the 2nd when I am interested in its peculiarities.

Comment: Great! 
But could you explain the difference between `9split +/imap` and `9split | /imap`?